# Female wires to connect 12V ECU to power supply?

Tags: wiring, jumper

I have extracted the ECU (engine control module) from car, however, this module has 3 pins that needs power input of 12V. Arduino jumper wires will not work as they won't withstand the current I need to run the ECU.

This is a picture of the ECU pins :

[image: ECU]

**My question is: How to make a female to male wires that can stand 3~5A ?**

And then I'm going to group them using an alligator clip and connect them to DC variable power supply to start diagnosing the ECU

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: @jsotola where to find female to male wires that can stand 3~5A ?

Comment: Get the connector for the ecu from a scrap car and use those wires - the pins will all be the correct size and, as a plus, you can use those to check other dignals as well.

Comment: @SolarMike I dont have a scrap car, I'm gonna have to buy the wires somewhere

Comment: `where to buy?` is a shopping question ... that is off topic here ... you can edit your post and ask `how to make?`

Comment: Scrap cars can be found in scrap yards or junk yards... you need to use Shank’s pony...

Comment: I'd second the idea of finding a mating connector at a junkyard, but barring that if you can get the cover off I might solder wires directly to the PCB to power it up.  You should be able to find components on the board that connect to the input supply that you can solder to.

Comment: Measure the width of those power terminals and then look for some female spade terminals to match.

Comment: Scrap cars can often also be found, one piece at a time, on eBay. Search for your model car + "ECU connector" and you might get lucky one day.

Comment: You can contact the manufacturer or parts depot and see if you can get a connector. I believe the best you will be able to do is purchase the harness(s). I do not understand how you are going to run this ECU, they are custom typically by the manufacturer. It will need several sensors etc how are you going to supply those signals.